# Executing multiple source files in sequence using R

Tags: r

I have multiple source files in R which I want to execute daily in sequence using one cron job.

The code looks like -

```
Master_script.R
...
...
tryCatch({
source(abc.R)
source(pqr.R)
source(xyz.R)
}, error=function(e) {
    print(e)})
...
...
```

In case there is an error in `abc.R`, an error is thrown and the rest of the `Master_script.R` is not executed. However, I want to execute the rest of the R files `pqr.R` and `xyz.R` incase `abc.R` fails.

In case there is an error in `abc.R`, is there a way to skip file `abc.R`, and continue executing the remaining source files?

FYI... I am not considering packing things up into a `R package` for now. Also, I don't want to create separate cron jobs.

Comment: try adding `tryCatch` in those scripts or have `break`

Comment: Something like following for each file? ```tryCatch({
source(abc.R)
}, error=function(e) {print(e)}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use tryCatch to avoid the Shinyapp crashing when encountering an error. See if this works. Good luck.

tryCatch(error = function(err) {return(error_value)},
source(abc.R)
)